# Flexbox Container with Child in it with position absolute

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, absolute

I'm new to React, and I'm currently building a slideshow on my website. Basically, I have a left arrow, the slide content, then the right arrow in my flexbox for my slideshow. However, to make my arrows on the edges of the screen I needed to use position absolute, which messes up my flexbox container. I figured out that absolutely positioned child items don't count in the flexbox of the parent, but is there a way around that? As of now, my image is overlapping with the left arrow. Thanks, and sorry if this is poorly written since I'm very new to this all. Code will be below.
Image:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkL3Z.jpg

```
import { ArrowBackIosOutlined, ArrowForwardIosOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons'
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import grocery from '../assets/grocery.png'

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
`

const Arrow = styled.div`
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff7f7;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: ${props => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
    right: ${props => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
`

const Slide = styled.div`
    width; 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`

const ImageContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
`

const Image = styled.img`
    height: 50%;
`

const InfoContainer = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
`

const Slider = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
        <Arrow direction="left">
            <ArrowBackIosOutlined/>
        </Arrow>
        <Wrapper>
            <Slide>
               <ImageContainer>
                    <Image src={https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80}/>
                </ImageContainer> 
            </Slide>
        </Wrapper>
        <Arrow direction="right">
            <ArrowForwardIosOutlined/>
        </Arrow>     
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

Comment: To fix the overlap, I would use `justify-content: center` on the parent of the slider item, and then add horizontal padding wide enough to cover the arrows. That way the content should stop before overlapping with your arrows.

Comment: @bluecouch ok, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. Is this just how things are with position absolute child items in flexbox then? or is it kind of like a bug?

Comment: It's the expected behaviour, `position: absolute` takes objects out of the document flow, so they won't interact with surrounding elements anymore.